# how to select the image from gallery by clicking on imageview on navigation drawer for user profile picture

Tags: java, android

I have created the navigation activity already,in which I want to make the image view on navigation drawer header as an user profile image.And the user selection of that image should done in gallery. I have searched a plenty of tutorials. I didn't get solution.Either I need code for it or comment a matching tutorial for this situation.Anyone help me with this.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
NavigationView navigationView = null;
Toolbar toolbar = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    DownloadFragment fragment = new DownloadFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.chat) {

        startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ChatFragment.class));
        return (true);
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.upload) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, UploadFlash.class));
        return (true);
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.download) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, DownloadFragment.class));
        return (true);
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, SettingsFragment.class));
        return (true);
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.offline) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, OfflineNotesFragment.class));
        return (true);
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.drawges) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, OfflineNotesFragment.class));
        return (true);
    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.chat) {
        // Handle the camera action
        ChatFragment fragment = new ChatFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.upload) {
        UploadFlash fragment = new UploadFlash();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.download) {
        DownloadFragment fragment = new DownloadFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        SettingsFragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.offline) {
        OfflineNotesFragment fragment = new OfflineNotesFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.drawges) {
        DrawingFragment fragment = new DrawingFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is your target sdk?

Comment: Target sdk is 25.

Comment: Then the answer below will not work, you will have to implement runtime permissions before the gallery is opened.

Comment: I have done a activity in the same project where user will be selecting an image from gallery and uploading it firebase storage.It works fine.The thing is,I don't how to make the user to select the image form gallery or file storage by clicking the image view in navigation drawer.

Comment: Because the navigation drawer activity has various xml files and one java file.I am confused with this only.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event on image click with this code:

```
@Override
public void onClick (View v){
try {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Activity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
    } else {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

and add this function:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
   switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
              startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);
            } else {
                //Error message
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: do I need to add onclick attribute to my navigation_header_main xml file.Will it working then.

Comment: also tell me where to add this intent part in my code.I am new to android development.

Comment: inside the xml file you have only the imageview, on your java code have to add the onClickEvent @loki_innocent

Comment: I upvoted this, but this will not work because his target sdk is 25, so he will have to implement runtime permissions.

Comment: you have add this permission in manifest file? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: I garentee you that it will not work if your target sdk is 24 and above and don't have runtime permission. I'm not talking about permissions in manifest. You can follow this answer but you will soon realise what I'm talking about.

Comment: I think you are saying that pop up menu that appears like "Allow to access the gallery